# Odd behaviour with Anchor Tag Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using areas in my .NET Core web application. I am also trying to use the **Anchor Tag Helper**s instead of the ugly looking @ notation like this:

```
 <a asp-area="Quizzes" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Quizzes</a>
```

But when they are rendered into HTML I see this URL:

```
 /Home/Index?area=Quizzes
```

Why isn't that coming out like the usual

```
/Quizzes/Home/Index
```

what am I missing here.

Comment: Nope that does not change how it gets rendered.

Comment: I haven't used Core yet, but the first question I can think of is: did you register your area(s)? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas

Comment: Yes there is a single route for all areas

Comment: can you show us your routes.

Answer (score 0):

```
  app.UseMvc(routes =>
  {

    //Order Matters...   
    routes.MapRoute(name: "areaRoute",
     template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
                 ///^^^^ required 


     routes.MapRoute(
      name: "default",
     template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  });
```

Then on the controller for `Home` it should be attributed with `[Area("Quizzes")]` which should be in the Controller folder within Area -> Quizzes, along with any other controllers that need to be in that Area.

Comment: The order does matter but that has no effect on what I am describing. My route spec has been like that since the beginning (when I added my first area). The only difference is my area route ends the template with /{id?}